# Impact of fitness function domain selection in multi-objective evolutionary optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I am using evolutionary algorithms e.g. the [NSGA-II algorithm](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/996017/) to solve unconstrained optimization problems with multiple objectives.

As my fitness functions sometimes have very different domains (e.g. **f1(x)** generates fitness values within **[0..1]** and **f2(x)** within **[10000..10000000]**) I am wondering if this has an effect on the search behaviour of the selected algorithm.

Does the selection of the fitness function domain (e.g. scaling all domains to a common domain from **[lb..ub]**) impact the solution quality and the speed of finding good solutions? Or is there no general answer to this question?

Unfortunately, I could not find anything on this topic. Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is related to the selection strategy implemented in the algorithm. In the case of the original NSGA II, selection is made using a mixture of pareto rank and crowding distance. While the pareto rank (i.e. the non dominated front id of a point) is not changing scaling the numerical values by some constant, the crowding distance does.

So the answer is yes, if your second objective is in [10000 .. 10000000]  its contribution to the crowding distance might be eating up the one of the other objective.

In algorithms such as NSGA II units count!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across your question and I have to disagree with the previous answer. If you read the paper carefully you will see that the crowding distance is supposed to be calculated in the **normalized** objective space. Exactly for the reason that one objective shall not dominating another.

My PhD advisor is Kalyanmoy Deb who has proposed NSGA-II and I have implemented the algorithm by myself (available in our evolutionary multi-objective optimization framework [pymoo](https://pymoo.org)). So I can state with certainty that normalization is supposed to be incorporated into the algorithm.
If you are curious about a vectorized crowding distance implementation feel free to have a look at `pymoo/algorithms/nsga2.py` in **pymoo** on [GitHub](https://github.com/msu-coinlab/pymoo).